# How to calculate average velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity, calculus

The position of an object moving along X-axis is given as $X=a+bt^2$ where $a=8.5\,\mathrm m$, $b=2.5\,\mathrm {m/s^2}$ and $t$ is measured in seconds. What is it's velocity at $t=0$ and $t=2.0$ s? What is the average velocity between $t=2.0s$ s and $t=4.0$ s?

I have no idea what to do. I have seen this in numerical in one book where they have used velocity $v=dx/dt$, but what does $d$ stand for? Is it delta($\Delta$)?

I am totally confused.

Comment: can you give me some basic idea about differentiation and integration so that i can solve this problem??

Comment: I am sorry i have done mistake in typing question. It is average velocity  between 2s and 4s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need calculus to answer this question.

You can calculate the average velocity based on the time interval and the distance travelled

$$v_{mean}=\frac{\Delta X}{\Delta t}=\frac{X(t_2)-X(t_1)}{t_2-t_1}=\frac{X(4.0s)-X(0.s)}{4.0s}.$$

Comment: $\Delta t$ is change in time so it should not be $4.0s-2.0s=2.0s$.

Comment: @Freddy you asked for average velocity between 0s and 4s. Then, you don't need information about 2.0s.

Comment: can you do one more step??

Comment: @Freddy what is the part you don't understand? There is not much more detail that you can do.

Comment: @Davidmh i got it average velocity will be $6.0*2.5=15m/s$